# What is the best way to learn Java EE practically?

Tags: jakarta-ee

What can be a good web application to start building while learning Java EE concepts, so that these concepts could be applied practically?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291279/getting-started-with-j2ee) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276245/which-book-would-you-recommend-for-entering-into-the-j2ee-world) questions. I would recommend to start from finding one or more books that suit your needs. You don't just need to learn SUN technologies (JSP, servlets, templates), but some open source frameworks (MVC, IoC, ORM) are also necessary. There are many books that feature a Web Site as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the books use the shopping cart example to illustrate the Java EE concepts and the various features of the Java EE specifications. I think this is a good enough web application to start learning the Java EE concepts. It's practical too.

Answer (score 0):

Start with reading a lot, like this -

http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/javaee-6.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/

http://www.lulu.com/items/volume_63/821000/821310/2/preview/978-1-4116-6824-9-preview.pdf

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition

Then do a simple Java EE in eclipse.