# How should a one start learning Java Enterprise Edition?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am a 4th year CS student . Since I'll be joining the corporate next year and I have been programming in Java Standard Edition , I want to learn Java EE (latest version) and do some projects on it. Can anyone guide me to the right path , probably tell me some beginner level to advanced level books. I stumbled upon a similar question and one of the answers had the link to the related books , but that link isn't active.Also if somebody knows good video tutorials then please mention them.

Link to the similar question : [Getting Started With Java EE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291279/getting-started-with-java-ee)

Also the person who asked this question was already developing we applications , but I am beginner.

Comment: Just as a heads up, this type of question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You should be able to view documentation, specs, and learning resources at its [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-ee/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you are willing to learn. Desktop or web applications.

If I were you, I would start learning [Eclipse RCP](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html), build a small app with some views and editors, then start to read on [Java EE6 with Glassfish3](http://www.apress.com/9781430228899/). This is by far the best EE book I've found out there, and it's available in PDF.

Tame the GF3 server, make a database, write some business logic, layer your app, apply design patterns.

On the other hand, if you want a web app, just pick a [Java Web Framework](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/the-curious-coders-java-web-frameworks-comparison-spring-mvc-grails-vaadin-gwt-wicket-play-struts-and-jsf/), write a small app, then read the EE6 book. As you can see, either way, you still have to read it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are starting try Head First Series.

[Head First Series](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfsvlt/)